# How to Destroy and Instantiate a GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject that I want to Destroy and Instantiate depending on button clicked. I don't really understand how it works but is it something like the code below? Then I attach the script on some gameobject then on onClick set via the function name.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CreateDestroyAR : MonoBehaviour {

    //PAGE HAS BEEN CREATED AS A PREFAB
    public GameObject Page;
    public void CreatePage() {
        Instantiate(Page);
    }

    public void DestroyPage()
    {
        Destroy(Page);
    }
}
```

Yes, they are "pages" which I can just use `setActive` for but one of the "page" needs to be destroyed when a different button is clicked and re-instantiated every time its corresponding button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CreateDestroyAR : MonoBehaviour {

    //PAGE HAS BEEN CREATED AS A PREFAB
    public GameObject Page;
    private GameObject instantiatedPage;
    public void CreatePage() {
       instantiatedPage = Instantiate(Page);
    }

    public void DestroyPage()
    {
        Destroy(instantiatedPage);
    }
}
```